# My 12V 10A circuit is not working properly

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, diy

I'm still quite new to electronics and I wanted to build myself a 12 V 10 A power supply for a different project. I followed this circuit design since it looked simple enough for me.

[image]

Did all the connections correctly, have an appropriately rated transformer (outputs about 13.4 V 12 A max), checked the transistor many times if I had the correct connections, even checked the datasheet. It somehow works, as I can power a fan and a LED light with it. However when I try to power the DC motor I have which draws about 2 A, it won't work. What would be the possible problem in this circuit I made?

Comment: The circuit found online does not work properly with the 0.1 ohms resistor. Maybe the website is run by schoolkids who did not calculate the resistance correctly. Next time get correct circuits from an engineer at a semiconductor manufacturer of the LM7812 like Texas Instruments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the resistance at the regulator input, which I shall call \$R_{REG}\$, is too low. Here's the circuit with some proper labels, and a more appropriate value for \$R_{REG}\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkOVuf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea is to make the transistors become conductive when the 7812 regulator has reached its maximum current handling capacity, and let them take over current passing duties. At full pelt, these transistors are each passing nearly 5A each, current which must flow through their emitter resistors, which I will call \$R_E\$. Each emitter resistor \$R_E\$, then, would have a voltage across it:

$$ V_{RE} = I_{RE} \times R_E = 5A \times 0.1\Omega = 0.5V $$

To turn these transistors on enough to pass 5A of current, their base-emitter junction voltage \$V_{BE}\$ needs to be about 1V. This voltage is provided by \$R_{REG}\$ in series with the regulator. Whatever voltage appears across that resistor is shared between \$R_E\$ and the base-emitter junction. So, to have that transistor pass 5A, the voltage across \$R_{REG}\$ will have to be about:

$$ V_{RREG} = V_{RE} + V_{BE} = 0.5V + 1.0V = 1.5V $$

The voltage \$V_{RREG}\$ developed by resistor \$R_{REG}\$ is due to current flowing through it and into the regulator. That means we require \$V_{RREG}\$ to reach 1.5V (so the transistors are switched on), long before the regulator's current \$I_{REG}\$ reaches the maximum it can handle. Let's say that's \$I_{REG(MAX)} = 1A\$.

As it stands, with \$R_{REG} = 0.1\Omega\$, and regulator current maxed-out at \$I_{REG} = 1A\$, we can use Ohm's law to find \$V_{RREG}\$:

$$ V_{RREG} = I_{REG} \times R_{REG} = 1A \times 0.1\Omega = 0.1V $$

That's nowhere near enough to turn on those transistors. Regulator current would have to be *many* times that for the transistors to even *begin* to react. The 7812 will start throttling current long before that happens, and that's why you can't get even 2A out of your supply.

We need to calculate an appropriate value for \$R_{REG}\$ that will develop 1.5V when only 1A is passing through it and into the regulator:

$$ R_{REG} = \frac{V_{RREG}}{I_{REG}} = \frac{1.5V}{1A} = 1.5\Omega $$

If you replaced the 0.1Ω resistor \$R_{REG}\$ with 1.5Ω, then your problem is solved, but another one arises.

Power \$P_{REG}\$ dissipated in the regulator, at full load, is:

$$ P_{REG} = I_{REG} \times (V_{IN}-V_{OUT}) = 1A \times (17V - 12V) = 5W $$

Unless you have a beefy heatsink on that 7812, it will overheat and shutdown very quickly. To keep the regulator cool without needing a heat sink, we should aim for \$P_{REG}=1W\$, and the maximum current corresponding to that will be:

$$ I_{REG} = \frac{P_{REG}}{V_{IN}-V_{OUT}} = \frac{1W}{17V-12V} = 0.2A $$

That's our new target regulator current \$I_{REG}\$ that should develop the required 1.5V across \$R_{REG}\$. In other words, we require the transistors to switch on, and take over current passing duties, when regulator current reaches 0.2A:

$$ R_{REG} = \frac{V_{RREG}}{I_{REG}} = \frac{1.5V}{0.2A} = 7.5\Omega $$

Setting \$R_{REG}=7.5\Omega\$, or a little more, say 8.2Ω, will permit the transistors to switch on properly, and limit regulator current to about 0.2A, which it should be fine with.

These are ballpark figures, to be honest, since I haven't checked what \$V_{BE}\$ will actually be, when transistor collector current is 5A, and I haven't accounted for base currents. It's a starting point though.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Based from all the replies I got here, it seems that the regulator resistor value from the internet schematic I got was not correct.

Answer (score 1):

How did you measure your 13.4 volts? Is that after rectification? Or is that 13.4 VAC, i.e. an rms value?

13.4 volts is insufficient input voltage for a 7812 to reliably give a 12V output. You need a higher input voltage for the 7812.

Your options include

- using a transformer with a higher secondary voltage
- increasing the size of your already large 47,000 uF capacitor to decrease the voltage sag.
- using a low drop out (LDO) voltage regulator instead of the 7812
- other options such as switching regulator

Comment: I checked the voltage output of the transformer before rectification. I'll try getting a higher voltage transformer and see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider adding reference designators and connection dots to your schematic.

Second, "it won't work" tells us nothing.  In what specific ways is the circuit not performing as desired?

Guesswork:

If things are connected the way I think they are, there is a problem with one resistor value.  The resistor between the bridge output and the regulator input (reference designators - !) is too small.

The two bypass transistors will not begin to conduct until there is at least 0.6 V across their base-emitter junctions.  That voltage is developed across the resistor by the output current going through it.  Usually, you want the bypass transistors to begin sharing the load current when approx. 10% to 25% of the load current is going through the regulator IC.

If we select a transition current of 0.1 A, then using Ohm's Law we can calculate that "the resistor" should have a value of 6 ohms.  At any output current above this, there will be approx. 0.6 V to 0.9 V (it increases as the load current increases) across "the resistor", causing the bypass transistors to conduct current around "the resistor" and the regulator, directly into the load.  This bypass current will increase until an equilibrium point is reached where the current through "the resistor" is just enough to create a voltage across the transistors base-emitter junctions that is just enough to cause enough conduction to bypass just enough current so the remaining current through "the resistor" is just enough.

It sounds circular because it is.  This is how negative feedback loops work.  For any output current above the design point (0.1 A in this example), the circuit is designed to maintain a constant current through "the resistor".  It shunts any load current above that value around "the resistor" and the regulator.  The regulator creates a constant output voltage, and the circuit apportions the current through two paths.

Comment: I just saw this circuit online and tried to build it and follow the schematic as accurately as possible. As for why it mostly doesn't work, is because while it can power a LED light and a 12v pc fan, the DC motor I used to test the PS does not run when I connect it to the output. I'll try to change that one resistor value to 6 ohms and see if it finally works properly.

Comment: Be sure to check the transistor and regulator pinouts.  Also, use a 1/4 W resistor.

Comment: 1/4 W resistor would work? Wouldn't it overheat or something?